# Why does an empty 200 create a fail in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, post

I've created a simple ajax request to post some json to my api. I've done this a couple times before in other pages, but suddenly I can't get this new call to work properly.

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/my-api-call",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({"pid": 5, "comment": $('#comment').val()})
});
request.done(function(data){
    console.log('weve got a succesful response!!');
})
request.fail(function(error){
    console.log('weve got an error!!!');
    console.log(error);
});
```

The call simply returns an empty 200 response, which I verify in the browser. But somehow the browser console constantly says `weve got an error!!!`. As you can see I also log the error, but I that is an object so full of information, that I have no idea what could be important in it. In that error object it also says the response is a plain 200 btw.

Seeing that this code is fairly simple, I can't really figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Are you sure it is not a CORS issue ? (*request to remove domain*)

Comment: What is the full response that your are getting in looking at your browser's network response info?

Comment: What does the error message say in the console? I am sure it tells you the problem.

Comment: I can't read this. Please, if just for posting on this site, don't write `weve`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you've set your `dataType` to `json`. So jquery is trying to parse your data (which is empty) to json. An empty result is not valid json.

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript
>   object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON
>   is rejected and a parse error is thrown. **As of jQuery 1.9, an empty
>   response is also rejected**; the server should return a response of null
>   or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON
>   formatting.)

### [From the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

so you should return `{}` or `null`

Comment: Ah! I always thought that the dataType referred to the data that was being sent. I just removed it and now it works like a charm. Thanks a million!

Comment: No, dataType is the resonse type: `String The type of data that you're expecting back from the server`. Also, no problem :)